# Open links in the ifram website within iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jupyter-notebook

I want to embed a jupyter notebook in my website and I want the users to navigate and open links in the same frame.

I'm using the following code to embed the notebook:

```
<iframe src="https://www.shyamooo.online/tree?" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
    <p>Sorry your browser does not support this.</p>
</iframe>
```

Usually in the jupyter notebook all the files are being opened in a separate tab. So when I click on the files from within the iframe they get opened in a new tab as well.

Is there a way where I can open these files within the iframe itself and not in a new tab? Or is there another way I can achieve this?

Comment: You don't have any control in the iframe. It is like a window to another URL. Anything inside that is controlled from there side. I can't imagine any way to get around this unfortunately.

Comment: i tried embedding above iframe in html page but i was not getting anything output in browser but you can  try to write jquery code to select <a> tags and add target="_self" ex: $('a').attr("target","_self");
also check this ,https://html.com/attributes/a-target/